# How to replace nan / fillna per group in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, fillna

I have the following data:

```
               type           group
0           Drought  Climatological
1               nan  Climatological
2         Explosion   Technological
3   Ground movement     Geophysical
4               nan     Geophysical
5          Ash fall     Geophysical
6          Rockfall     Geophysical
7          Ash fall     Geophysical
8               nan   Technological
9         Explosion   Technological
10              nan  Meteorological
```

```
data_pd = pd.DataFrame({'type':['Drought','nan','Explosion','Ground movement','nan','Ash fall','Rockfall','Ash fall','nan','Explosion','nan'],  
                        'group':['Climatological','Climatological','Technological','Geophysical','Geophysical',  
                        'Geophysical','Geophysical','Geophysical','Technological','Technological','Meteorological']})
```

How can I replace the `'nan'` depending on the group?

###### Below is my current approach:

I want to replace `nan` strings that match with specific strings from the next row in another column by some alternative string.

Here's a sample of data from my dataset where it seizes to work this was an output from `pd.to_dict()` I wanted to keep it as it is to replicate my issue.:

```
for ty, go in zip(data_pd['type'].values, data_pd['group'].values):
    if ty == 'nan' and go == 'Climatological':
        #ty = ['Drought']
        print(ty) #prints nothing as it did not work
```

Comment: no it doesn't work. You are not chaning the value in your data, but only in the iterator

Comment: @Mahrkeenerh I was going to merge the iterator output with the dataset by storing it in a list, as I don't know any other way of doing it.

Comment: Also, frame your questions following the guidelines given by SO. Minimal reproducible example is enough, do not post your entire code and test data in your question.

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran It's not my entire code, it's a sample of my code which produces the problem but the data seems no different to the first example.

Comment: @me.limes is you goal to fill missing values per group? then check the second part of [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69897318/16343464)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do **NOT** iterate for this kind of task, this is inefficient!

You can use masks and `pandas.where` to apply your filter:

```
data_pd['type'] = data_pd['type'].mask(data_pd['type'].eq('nan') & data_pd['group'].eq('Climatological'), 'Drought')
```

output:

```
               type           group
0           Drought  Climatological
1           Drought  Climatological
2         Explosion   Technological
3   Ground movement     Geophysical
4               nan     Geophysical
5          Ash fall     Geophysical
6          Rockfall     Geophysical
7          Ash fall     Geophysical
8               nan   Technological
9         Explosion   Technological
10              nan  Meteorological
```

##### much cleaner solution

If your objective is to fillna per group, you could use a dictionary and `groupy`:

```
subs = {'Climatological': 'Drought', 'Technological': 'foo'}

(data_pd.replace('nan', pd.NA)
        .groupby('group')
        .apply(lambda g: g.fillna(subs.get(g.name, 'nan')))
)
```

output:

```
               type           group
0           Drought  Climatological
1           Drought  Climatological
2         Explosion   Technological
3   Ground movement     Geophysical
4               nan     Geophysical
5          Ash fall     Geophysical
6          Rockfall     Geophysical
7          Ash fall     Geophysical
8               foo   Technological
9         Explosion   Technological
10              nan  Meteorological
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for index, row in data_pd.iterrows():
    if row["type"] == 'nan' and row["group"] == 'Climatological':
        data_pd["type"][index] = "Drought"
```

I tried to match your code as closely as possible to be more concise and user-friendly.